# How to pull data from database and display in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display details of a receipt number when the user enters the number and do a search. After the user should be able to edit the details. I pull the information for the driver; however, when I click to edit the list of drivers from the database is not shown; but just the actual data.

```
private void BindData()

{
    int parsedValue;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "PP_spSearchReturnCrate";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtReceiptNo.Text.Trim()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@receiptNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtReceiptNo.Text.Trim();
    }
    cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
    sqlConn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sqlDa.Fill(dt);



    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {



        String DATE = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["returnDte"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        txtReturnDte.Text = DATE;
        txtReceipt.Text = dt.Rows[0]["receiptNo"].ToString(); //Where ColumnName is the Field from the DB that you want to display
        ddlCustomer.Text = dt.Rows[0]["CUSTNAME"].ToString();

        //ddlDriver.Text = dt.Rows[0]["driverName"].ToString();
        //ListItem lis = new ListItem(dt.Rows[0]["driverName"].ToString());
        //ddlDriver.Items.Add(lis);
        ddlUnitId.Text = dt.Rows[0]["unitId"].ToString();
        txtNumber.Text = dt.Rows[0]["qtyReturned"].ToString();
        txtLocation.Text = dt.Rows[0]["custLocation"].ToString();
        //ddlDriver.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //ListItem lis = new ListItem(dt.Rows[0]["driverName"].ToString());
        //ddlCustomer.Items.Add(lis);
        ddlDriver.DataSource = dt;
        ddlDriver.DataBind();
        ddlDriver.DataTextField = "driverName";
        ddlDriver.DataValueField = "driverName";
        ddlDriver.DataBind();
        //ListItem li = new ListItem(dt.Rows[0]["driverName"].ToString());
        //ddlDriver.Items.Add(li);
        Panel1.Visible = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm kind of a n00b myself, but out of curiosity if you set a break point next to your DataSource line and run it, does it get that far?

Comment: yes it does get that far

Comment: also just noticed you have a DataBind() in there twice. Get rid of that duplicate and move your `DataSource`, `DataBind`, `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` above and outside of your `if` statement, put those lines right after you `Fill` your datatable. `DataBind` should come last

Comment: Instead using DropDownList, why dont you use ASPxComboBox? You can bind it with DB by choosing DataSource

Comment: Can give me an example of that would would? Would that still pull the data from the database and when the clicks edit see a drop down list from the database

Comment: I'm not seeing combobox as an option

Comment: Morning Sue, does the `SELECT` in your stored procedure return the list of things that you want to show in the drop down?

Comment: It is not a list it should return but the actual value in the field in the database. Then when the user clicks the edit button then it would show the list from another stored procedure. So basically it’s two sp but I don’t how to work it out.

Comment: Can we see your stored procedure?

Comment: SELECT receiptNo,returnDte,Date,custName,custLocation,driverName,unitId,qtyReturned from Receipt where receiptNo=@receiptNo

Comment: okay and is one of those columns the one you want to use to populate the drop down?

Comment: we're gonna get this, one thing I've learned since becoming a developer is to simplify things, start with the first thing and get that working, then move on. Let's get your drop down populated first, then we can worry about the edit button. What is it you're trying to display in the drop down? Also, I'm leaving early today but I'll be back at it on Monday

Comment: If I were you I would start by writing a SELECT that returns exactly what you're wanting to have appear in the drop down and nothing else, and hang onto it

Answer (score 0):

Your `BindData()` method is a good start, but it's little cluttered. And I am by no means an expert, but I'm going trim out some of the stuff you don't need for now and we'll see if we can get your drop down populated.

First you'll need to add a couple using directives at the top of your code behind page if they're not there already:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

This is how I was shown:

```
private void BindData()
{
    // Wrap the whole thing in a using() because it automatically closes the connection
    // when it's done so you don't have to worry about doing that manually
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name of your connection string"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            // Set the releveant properties like you already had                
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "PP_spSearchReturnCrate";

            // Double check that the connection is open                    
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            // Create your SqlDataAdapter and fill it with the data from your stored procedure                     
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            // Then set that as the DataSource, and finally bind it to your drop down
            ddlDriver.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ddlDriver.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

And if you'd like the default option in your drop down to say something other than whatever comes first from your stored procedure you can set a property called `AppendDataBoundItems` to true, then manually add a `ListItem` to your drop down, and set its `Value` to -1 (to get it to show at the top):

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlDriver" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="Please Select" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```